# Binding the selected value to dynamically created dropdown jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I've created dynamic dropdowns inside a datatable. There are three dropdowns out of which one dropdown is controlled by a control outside the datatable. I've problems with other two dropdowns. I get the value bound with the  `<select>` but I'm unable to show the selected value. This is how I tried:

```
   var a = 0;   
        var b = 0;
        var c = 0;
        var d = 0;
        var e = 0;

    MomActivity = $("#MomActivity").DataTable({
                "sDom": "t",
                "ajax":{
                    "url": "../api/momapi.php?action=getmombyid",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "data": {"MomID": <?php echo $_GET["MomID"]; ?>}    
                },
                "destroy": true,
                "ordering": false,
                "columns": [
                            {
                                "title": "Project", "data": "projectid", "render": function(data, type, row){
                                    myFunction(data , "Project_"+a);
                                    return '<select class="form-control selectProjectID" id="Project_'+a+'" name="ProjectID[]" valueid="'+ data +'"></select>';
                                }   
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "What", "data": "what", "render": function(data, type, row){
                                    return  '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="What[]" value="'+ data +'">';            
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "For", "data": "momfor", "render": function(data, type, row){
                                    var UserSide = "";
                                    var CustomerSide = "";  
                                    if(data == "0"){
                                        UserSide = 'checked="checked"';                                 
                                        CustomerSide = "";                                  
                                    } else if(data == "1") {
                                        CustomerSide = 'checked="checked"';                                 
                                        UserSide = "";                                      
                                    }   

                                    return  '<input type="radio" name="MomFor_'+b+'" class="MomFor" '+UserSide+' value="0"> For User Side &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input type="radio" class="MomFor" name="MomFor_'+b+'" '+CustomerSide+' value="1"> For Customer Side';            
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "Who", "data": "who", "render": function(data, type, row){
                                    return  '<select class="form-control selectWho" name="Who_'+d+'" id="Who_'+c+'" valueid="'+ data +'">';         
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "When", "data": "whentime", "render": function(data, type, row){
                                    return  '<input type="text" class="form-control whendate" name="When[]" value="'+ moment(data).format("DD-MM-YYYY") +'">';          
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "Status", "data": "status", "render": function(data, type, row){


                                return  '<select class="form-control status"  valueid="'+ data +'" name="Status_'+e+'" disabled><option value="0"<?= $data->status == '0' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Not Started</option><option value="1"<?= $data->status == '1' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>In Progress</option><option value="2"<?= $data->status == '2' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Hold</option><option value="3"<?= $data->status == '3' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Completed</option></select>';          
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "...", "render": function(data, type, row){
                                return '<input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm remove" value="Remove" name="remove" id="remove">';  


                                }
                            }

                ],
                "drawCallback": function(settings){
                    $(".selectProjectID").each(function(){
                            if($(this).find("option").length == 0){
                                $(this).fillSelect(projectid,"projectid","projectname",0,1).val($(this).attr("valueid"));
                            }                   
                    });
                    $(".selectWho").each(function(){
                        if($(this).find("option").length == 0){
                            console.log($(this).attr("id"));
                            console.log($(this).attr("valueid"));
                            $(this).val($(this).attr("valueid")).trigger("change");
                        }                   
                    });
                    $(".status").each(function(){
                        if($(this).find("option").length > 0){
                            console.log($(this).attr("valueid"));
$(this).val($(this).attr("valueid")).trigger("change");
                        }                   
                    });
                    $(".MomFor").each(function(){
                         if (!$(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '0') {
                                var TaskStatus = $(this).parent().next('td').next('td').next('td').find('select');
                                TaskStatus.attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
                                TaskStatus.val("0");    
                                $(this).parent().next('td').find('select').removeAttr('disabled');
                         }  
                         else if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '1'){
                                var StaffSelect = $(this).parent().next('td').find('select');                           
                                StaffSelect.prop('disabled', true).val("");
                                $(this).parent().next('td').next('td').next('td').find('select').removeAttr('disabled');

                         }          
                    });


                },
                "rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
                    $('td > input.remove', row).off("click").on("click",function(){
                        MomActivity.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
                    });
                    $('td > input.whendate', row).datetimepicker({ format: "DD-MM-YYYY" });
                    $(".selectProjectID", row).on('change', function() {
                        myFunction(jQuery("#"+this.id).val(), this.id);
                    });
                     $(document).on("change", '.MomFor', function() {
                         //alert(this.value);
                            if ( $(this).val() == '0') {
                                //MyNotif.Show("Allot Thai Gayo Bhai", "success");
                                //$(".MomFor td:nth-child(4)").html();
                                //$(this).parent().next('td').next('td').next('td').find('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                var TaskStatus = $(this).parent().next('td').next('td').next('td').find('select');
                                TaskStatus.attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
                                TaskStatus.val("0");    
                                $(this).parent().next('td').find('select').removeAttr('disabled');
                                 //$(this).parent().nextAll('td:2').css("background-color", "yellow");
                            }
                            else if ( $(this).val() == '1') {
                                //$(this).parent().next('td').find('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                var StaffSelect = $(this).parent().next('td').find('select');                           
                                StaffSelect.prop('disabled', true).val("");
                                $(this).parent().next('td').next('td').next('td').find('select').removeAttr('disabled');
                                //$(this).parent().next('td').find('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                            }
                     });
                     $()
                },
                "fnCreatedRow": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){
                    a = a + 1;
                    b = b + 1;
                    c = c + 1;
                    d = d + 1;
                    e = e + 1;
                }           
            });
```

I get the correct console. It shows `Who_0, 3, Who_1, 0`. I want to display the name associated with value 3 as selected. Similarly with status. 
I can see this in inspect element:

```
<select id="Who_0" class="form-control selectWho" name="Who_0" valueid="3"></select>
<select id="Who_1" class="form-control selectWho" name="Who_1" valueid="0"></select>

<select class="form-control status" valueid="0" name="Status_0"></select>
<select class="form-control status" valueid="3" name="Status_1"></select>
```

This is the generated select:

```
<select id="Who_0" class="form-control selectWho" name="Who_0" valueid="3">
   <option value="0">---Select---</option>
<option value="3">Yogeshwaran</option>
<option value="1">Samyuktha</option>
<option value="0">---Select---</option>

</select>
```

I've also shown the generated select dropdown. This is generated dynamically.

But I don't know why is it not showing the selected value? So, how to show the selected value? What should I add or change?

Comment: Hello @duddosai , what is the attribute _valueid_ ? can you put the entire select with options (copy/past your generate HTML). I have notice you have length == 0 for the selectWho and length > 0 for the status. is this normal ?

Comment: @cedric.salaun: Having length==0 or length>0 is not a big deal, anyway it will come inside. Instead of  console.log($(this).attr("valueid"));, if I put alert($(this).attr("valueid"));, it is binding.

Comment: you can try with : $(this).find("option:selected").text() for access to the selected value.

Comment: @cedric.salaun: Can you give me the full statement?

Comment: here is a fidle : https://jsfiddle.net/v77uub3n/

Comment: @cedric.salaun: It's not working bro.